# Server side application vs end side protocols (RESTful/SOAP)

Tags: java, web-services

I'm very new to web services stuff, probably learning ABC 
as quickly as possible. I've got few basics questions:

1. What is endpoint here? I was reading about REST/SOAP it looks
   like its way transporting data (XML/JSON).  And REST is mainly
   architecture style.
2. Is Java servlet just server side application?
   (But it has doGet/post etc which REST has too) --
   From comment: Java servlet can be used to implement
   REST.

Comment: StackOverflow questions should really be one question per post. In any case, you should do some research before you ask. You should be reading a lot more about REST in general, and also about servlets. I think the main point you are missing is that servlets can be used to implement REST if you so wish.

Comment: Maybe you should ask it on **Programmers** community, not **StackOverflow**.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you're right, I'm reading it simultaneously .. which I'm overwhelmed with .. hence I thought of taking some help as well. Also removed my last two question. Hopefully that helps me!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here, I would suggest him/her to read first 3 chap of this:
Java Web Services: Up and Running, 2nd Edition

Was really helpful.

1) What is endpoint here? I was reading about REST/SOAP it looks
like its way transporting data (XML/JSON).  And REST is mainly
architecture style.

Yep, its nothing but java application calling you Servlet and 
doing "something" with the result..